# Multi plot corrections

Tags: r

From the data and code below I tried to make a multiplot but the problem is that plastic consumption is overlapping on plastic production I want both clustered each other not overlap.

```
structure(list(Country = c("China", "Indonesia", "Vietnam", "Thailand", 
"Egypt", "India", "Turkey", "Brazil", "United States", "Russia"
), 
Plastic.Consumption = c(44.14201935, 12.87658986, 23.6336878, 
52.92058216, 13.93164324, 6.994354455, 64.77526757, 31.53076177, 
87.30070657, 32.01972449), 
Plastic.Production.Kt. = c(42421L, 
2258L, 387L, 5881L, 411L, 7211L, 939L, 5860L, 33985L, 3487L), 
    
Plastic.Waste.Mismanagemet..kt. = c(8819.716784, 3216.855605, 
    1833.819141, 1027.739178, 967.0123574, 599.8191155, 485.937142, 
    471.4039969, 275.4244968, 80.75948103)), class = "data.frame",  row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

```
data=read.csv("PPPP.csv")

library(ggplot2)

library(tidyr)

library(dplyr)

 ggplot(data) + 
   geom_col(aes(x = Country, y = Plastic.Production.Kt.), size = 1, color = "black", fill = "blue") + 
   geom_col(aes(x = Country, y = 400*Plastic.Consumption), size = 1, color="black", fill = "red") + 
   scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./400, name = "Plastic Consumption"))+ 
   geom_line(aes(x = Country, y = Plastic.Waste.Mismanagemet..kt.), size = 2, color="black", group = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to *dodge* the bars. Currently you are just plotting one over the other. Because you have two different calls to `geom_col`, you are simply drawing one over the other. You need to reshape your data so that you have both plastic consumption and production in a single column, with a different column labelling each value as to whether it refers to production or consumption. This is known as *long format*. Once you have this, you can map the fill color to the production or consumption. This will not only allow you to dodge the bars, but will also create a legend. This plot really needs a legend, because at the moment you have no way of knowing which color refers to production and which to consumption.

For the same reason, you should map the line to the color aesthetic so that it appears in the legend. Otherwise, there is no indication what the line means.

```r
data %>%
  mutate(Plastic.Consumption = 400 * Plastic.Consumption) %>%
  pivot_longer(2:3) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(x = Country, y = value, fill = name), 
           size = 1, color = "black", position = "dodge") + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Country, y = Plastic.Waste.Mismanagemet..kt.,
                color = "Mismanagement"), 
            size = 2, group = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "black", name = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Plastic Production (Kt)",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./400, name = "Plastic Consumption")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"), name = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, you are a life-saver